# Is there any saving this Chinese Evergreen? I'm a newbie and am not sure what the issue is

Tags: leaves

The leaves are becoming pale, especially for that one stalk. They are also slightly curling under. The stalk has that odd dry spot too and the color of them aren't healthy looking.

What's the problem? What should I do at this point to try and salvage this plant(if I can)?

TIA
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you are using peat moss or coco peat and perlite mixture. How much water you are giving. And stalk has dry-ish look.

i think you are over watering

```
|_ did you make the holes in that ceramic pot?
   |_ Most probably the roots are rot that's why leaves are drooping.
       |_ Either fungus gnats infestation 
       |_ or maybe you over fertilize it (Happen to me one, i added too much fertilizer to Aloe vera plant)
```